# How to refresh partial view async / await Azure Event Hubs?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, async-await, azure-eventhub

I have been stuck on a case for a while now, and i hope someone can help me out.
I am trying to receive data from an EventHub from Azure and to display these data (in real-time) on an ASP.NET page, using MVC.

I found a way to create an async method which would await to receive an event, and i refreshed this method and partial view with jQuery each second, but i found that this gave me too much instability over time and it would end in an endless loop of errors.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        time = DateTime.Now;
        list = new List<TestEntity>();
        TestEntity t = new TestEntity();
        list.Add(t);
        await Initialize();
        return View(list);
    }

public async Task<ActionResult> RefreshLatest()
    {
        try
        {
            var message = await consumer.ReceiveAsync();
            if (message != null)
            {
                TestEntity t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestEntity>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.GetBytes()));
                list.Add(t);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("exception on receive {0}", exception.Message);
        }

        return PartialView("Latest", list);
    }

 private static async Task Initialize()
    {

        EventHubClient eventHubClient = getEventHubClient(SharedAccessKeyName, SharedAccessKey, NamespaceURI, EventHubName, ConnectionString);
        EventHubConsumerGroup consumerGroup = eventHubClient.GetDefaultConsumerGroup();


        consumer = await consumerGroup.CreateReceiverAsync(partitionId, DateTime.Now, receiverEpoch); // All messages

    }

    public static EventHubClient getEventHubClient(string SharedAccessKeyName, string SharedAccessKey, string NamespaceURI, string EventHubName, string ConnectionString)
    {
        //Create EventHub
        TokenProvider td = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(SharedAccessKeyName, SharedAccessKey);
        NamespaceManager manager = new NamespaceManager(NamespaceURI, td);
        var description = manager.CreateEventHubIfNotExists(EventHubName);

        //Create EventHubClient
        EventHubClient client = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString + ";EntityPath=" + EventHubName);
        return client;
    }
```

And here is my Index View:

http://puu.sh/gDQUj/cb816b8870.png

I hope you can see what i'm trying to accomplish and how this fails.

Comment: AFAICT, your `RefreshLatest` uses `consumer` without ever assigning it a value. It would help if you post the details of your exception ("instability" and "fails" are just way too imprecise), and also post a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).